# How to use "import" in node REPL

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, read-eval-print-loop, es6-modules

Using the Node.js [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), how can you [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) modules using ecmascript syntax? Does any version of the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) REPL allow this now?

In Node.js v10.16.0, I'm accessing the REPL using this command:

```
node --experimental-modules
```

source: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

[image]

CommonJS is ancient technology. Is Node.js still under active development? I wonder if the [deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno) REPL can do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**You cannot use static `import` statements (e.g. `import someModule from "some-module"`), at the moment.** I'm not aware of any efforts/tickets/pull requests/intents to change that.

You can use `import()` syntax to load modules! This returns a promise. So for example you can create a variable `someModule`, start importing, & after done importing, set `someModule` to that module:

```
let someModule
import("some-module")
  .then( loaded=> someModule= loaded)
```

Or you can directly use the import in your promise handler:

```
import("some-module").then(someModule => someModule.default())
```

For more complex examples, you might want to use an async Immediately Invoked Function Expression, so you can use `await` syntax:

```
(async function(){
    // since we are in an async function we can use 'await' here:
    let someModule = await import("some-module")
    console.log(someModule.default())
})()
```

last, if you start Node.JS with the `--experimental-repl-await` flag, you can use async directly from the repl & drop the async immediately invoked function:

```
let someModule = await import("some-module")

// because you have already 'await'ed
// you may immediately use someModule,
// whereas previously was not "loaded"
console.log(someModule.default())
```

Comment: What does `"some-module"` in the  import` function corresponds to ?

Comment: @cassepipe "some-module" is just a hypothetical example. You'd replace that with the actual module you want to import.

Answer (score 0):

Given the static nature of import statements and that the engine needs to know all static imports (before processing any non-import related code). You can see how the import statement really isn't compatible with interactive REPL support.

For example, import statements are allowed in the middle or end of a file, but they're hoisted and processed before "non-static-import related code".

What should the REPL do if you type a static import statement at the end of your REPL session?

It can't easily go back and rerun all your prior commands in light of this potentially fundamental change!

I didn't think about that until reading [this](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2629#issuecomment-509927814). Thanks Kevin Qian who also has [ideas](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2629#issuecomment-509929774).

Comment: If key parts of the language don't work in it, you don't have a working repl.

Comment: @AdamC : Did I claim otherwise? Keep in mind, my answer was same day of the question. The other answer came the next year!

Comment: This is not an issue introduced by `import`. In classic JS `var` declarations are hoisted as well, so theoretically code you typed earlier in a REPL session could have changed behaviour if ran again after you type a `var foo` statement. As a REPL user I understand that whatever I type now will not affect code that already ran, so it is a non-issue really.